# How can I combine HF and LF components of an image?

Tags: matlab

I separated the High Frequency (HF) component and low-frequency (LF) component from an image. After this step, I applied some denoising technique to the HF and LF. Afterwards I want to combine them together. How can I do that this?

I used the below code for decomposition

```
%// Load an image
Orig = double(rgb2gray(imread('lena.jpg')));
O=ROFdenoise(Orig, 12);
O=uint8(O);
figure, imshow(O)
%// Transform
Orig_T = dct2(Orig);
%// Split between high - and low-frequency in the spectrum (*)
cutoff = round(0.5 * 226);
High_T = fliplr(tril(fliplr(Orig_T), cutoff));
Low_T = Orig_T - High_T;
%// Transform back
High = idct2(High_T);

Low = idct2(Low_T);
```

Comment: `Low_T = Orig_T - High_T;` separates them. Solve for `Orig_T`in this equation to rejoin them. Or are you looking for something else that you did not explain?

Comment: Could you show more of the code? What method for decomposition did you use?

Comment: I added the code above

Answer (score 1):

I've commented out `ROFdenoise` because I don't know what it does. If you've split your image in the frequency domain, you want to combine it back together in frequency too. Also; I've added some plotting to make it easier to see what's happening.

```
%// Load an image
Orig = double(rgb2gray(imread('Lenna.png')));
%O=ROFdenoise(Orig, 12);
O=Orig; % No denoising before DCT
O=uint8(O);

figure(1), subplot(2,2,1), imshow(O), title('Before')
%// Discrete Cosine Transform
T = dct2(Orig);
%// Split between high - and low-frequency in the spectrum (*)
cutoff = round(0.5 * 226);
highT = fliplr(tril(fliplr(T), cutoff));
lowT = T - highT;
%//Do some denoising
highT = 0*highT;
subplot(2,2,2), imshow(highT), title('High T')
subplot(2,2,4), imshow(lowT), title('Low T')
%// Combine back
denoiseT = highT + lowT;
%// Transform back
denoiseO = uint8(idct2(denoiseT));
subplot(2,2,3), imshow(denoiseO), title('After')
```

Also; here is [Lenna](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Lenna)